# Rails, devise связь belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Сделал пробный проект по мануалу [Блог](http://rusrails.ru/getting-started-with-rails)

Потом добавил гем devise, регистрация, авторизация работает.

Теперь хочу сделять связь моделей User и Articles. Пользователь может иметь много статей, статья принадлежит только 1-у пользователю.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :article

devise :database_authenticatable,
     :registerable,
     :recoverable,
     :rememberable,
     :trackable,
     :validatable
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true,
        length: {minimum: 5}
end
```

Отредактировал файл миграции

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    change_table:articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

И тут первые вопросы, делаю *rails db:migrate* в базе обновлений не происходит ( таблици уже были созданны ранее, сейчас их требуется обновить.
Ну а дальше соответственно при попытке сделать новую статью получаю ошибку

> unknown attribute 'user_id' for Article.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def create
  @article = current_user.article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы отредактировать столбцы в бд, нужно:

1) либо откатить до предыдущей миграции (в dev среде, в production так делать нельзя:)

```
rails db:rollback
```

Исправить/добавить что нужно и накатить заново `rails db:migrate`

2) либо создать новую миграцию
`rails g migration AddUserIdToArticle` и в ней уже добавить столбец `user_id`